# Display animatable instead of text on a button when clicked

Tags: android-layout, button

I am trying to build a button with a progress bar which is displayed in the center of the button and instead of text, as soon as the button is tapped, and while some background processing takes place.
What I am doing is to have a custom button and set the animatable as a drawable left to the button, and in onDraw to move the animatable in the center of the button. However, for a short period of time after the button is tapped, I do not know why there are 2 progress bars on the button.

```
public class ButtonWithProgressBar extends Button {
protected int progressId = R.drawable.progress_bar;
protected Drawable progress;
protected CharSequence buttonText;

@Override
public void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type) {
    super.setText(text, type);
    if (Strings.notEmpty(text)) {
        buttonText = text;
    }
}

public void startSpinning()
{
    if(isSpinning()){
        return;
    }

    progress = getContext().getResources().getDrawable(progressId);
    final Drawable[] old = getCompoundDrawables();
    setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(old[0], old[1], progress, old[3]);
    setEnabled(false);

    if(progress instanceof Animatable){
        ((Animatable)progress).start();
    }
    setText("");

}

public void stopSpinning()
{
    if(!isSpinning()){
        return;
    }

    if(progress instanceof Animatable){
        ((Animatable)progress).stop();
    }
    setEnabled(true);
    setText(buttonText);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    if (progress != null) {
        final int drawableHeight = progress.getIntrinsicHeight();
        final int drawableWidth = progress.getIntrinsicWidth();
        final int drawableTop = (getHeight() - drawableHeight) / 2;
        final int drawableLeft = (getWidth() - drawableWidth) / 2;
        progress.setBounds(drawableLeft, drawableTop, drawableLeft + drawableWidth, drawableTop + drawableHeight);

        progress.draw(canvas);
    }
}
```

}

And this is displayed for a short period after tap, before everything looking as I want:
[image]

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.Updated code to a working version.